# Additional Tabs in Product Detail Page

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I just add some additional attributes on magento stores and I see it on product detail page. But when I duplicate this code below, its not working. I need to add 2 custom attributes so I will have, DESCRIPTION (which is already given), SPECIFICATION (custom), DELIVERY (custom) and REVIEW (given) TABS.

I'm editing it on catalog.xml file

```
 <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
        <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
        <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
 </block>
```

Answer (score 2):

I accomplished this in 1.9 CE by adding the following code to local.xml within the layout folder of my theme (you can create the file if it is not there already):

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.models" as="models" template="catalog/product/view/models.phtml">
        <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
        <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Models Supported</value>    </action>
    </block>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

and adding the following file to `magentoroot/app/design/frontend/themepackage/themename/template/catalog/product/view/models.phtml`

```
 <?php  $ingredients = $this->getProduct()->getData('model_support'); 
 echo $ingredients;
 ?>
```

In this case 'model_support' represents the particular attribute I have chosen to display, you must reference a relevant attribute within your store. Also verify that the attribute properties is set to yes, Visible on Product View Page on Front-end.

Also I wanted to prevent the Additional Data tab from displaying, so I also added the following code:

```
<reference name="product.info.tabs">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <child>product_additional_data</child>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Note: you will need to update your paths to use the relevant paths for EE and your theme configuration

Comment: Hi Joshua, I cannot find my local.xml? Is this something I should create and upload it? If I will upload it, what directory should it be?

Comment: Yes you can create the file using notepad and name it local.xml, place the file into your magento installation at this path: magentoroot/app/design/frontend/themepackage/themename/layout/local.xml

Comment: Hi Joshua, I followed your instructions but in my case, it doesn't seem to work? hhmm

Comment: Try to verify your attribute settings, I edited my answer

Comment: I corrected the models.phtml code and also please verify that the attribute code matches a working attribute on your store.

Comment: I already created the attribute but still not working. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16550/discussion-between-alyssa-reyes-and-joshua34com).